# Big-O of Equations: How to understand it.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

So from what I understand, Big-O notation is a way to show that $f(n)$ is no more than the growth rate of $g(n)$ therefore meaning at some point in g(n), there is a value c and $n_0$ such that $c\cdot g(n)>f(n)$ for $n\geq n_0$, where $c>0$ and $n_0\geq 1$.

So for example, we have:

Find Big-O of $3n^3+20n^2+5$
$f(n)=3n^3+20n^2+5$, $g(n)=n^3$
$3n^3+20n^2+5\leq cn^3$

How do I find $c$ and $n_0$?

I looked up the answer and it's $c=4$ and $n_0=21$ but I'm not sure how we got there, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is a general way to get $c$ and $n_0$, you have to prove in each individual case that the function meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac{3n^3+20n^2+5}{n^3}=3+\frac{20}{n}+\frac{5}{n^3}\rightarrow 3$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $c$ can be any number larger then $3$. Fix $c>3$.
We want to find $n_0$ so that $n>n_0$ implies $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<c$, or equivalently,
$\frac{20}{n}+\frac{5}{n^3}<3-c$. But
$$\frac{20}{n}+\frac{5}{n^3}<\frac{20}{n}+\frac{5}{n}=\frac{25}{n}\text{.}$$
Thus we can choose $n_0$ to be any integer larger than $\frac{25}{c-3}$.

Comment: Let $c=4$ and your estimate picks $n_0\ge25$. OP wants $n_0=21$